# DataGridView Winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

every time, i press btnAgregar, add "productos" to list.

only the first time the gridview show the first record of the list

after the list grows, but the datagridview don't refrash, showing only the first record.

```
List<Entidades.Productos> ProductosVenta = new List<Productos>();

 private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Entidades.Productos productos = new Entidades.Productos();
            productos = Datos.Productos.ObtenerFormaPagoPorId(int.Parse(txtId.Text));
            ProductosVenta.Add(productos);

            gvVenta.DataSource = ProductosVenta;
        }
```

Comment: this way don't work!!!  the list "ProductoVenta" accumulates data but the grid only show the first record

Answer (score 1):

the solution is make null the data source before asing the list

```
ProductosVenta.Add(productos);
gvVenta.DataSource = null; // this does the trick
gvVenta.DataSource = ProductosVenta;
```